# The [apply] and related tags - how to reorganize?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

Currently the [apply](/questions/tagged/apply) tag is used inconsistently, There are 470 questions under this tag. It has 2 problems.

1) The tag description refers only to the `apply()` function in the R programming language. Currently 331 questions are also tagged with [r](/questions/tagged/r). The rest are tagged with a variety of languages, but JavaScript and related tags are most common. My initial idea was to remove all of the [apply](/questions/tagged/apply) tags from questions which are not related to R, but it seems like there is a `.apply` in JavaScript which many questions refer to. Should  I just remove the [apply](/questions/tagged/apply) tag from these or should an new tag be created to house the JavaScript questions?

2) Within the questions about R there are also some problems. In R there are a variety of closely related functions which take in some sort of data structure (matrix, list etc.) and apply a function to it. These are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega). Many of these have their own tags such as [mapply](/questions/tagged/mapply), [tapply](/questions/tagged/tapply), [sapply](/questions/tagged/sapply) and [lapply](/questions/tagged/lapply). There is also the closely related `aggregate()` function, which has its own ambiguous tag, and a package of related functions called 'plyr' with its own tag. The problems come as very often someone will write a question under one tag - such as how to use `apply()` to accomplish something, and the answer will be to use `lapply()` or `aggregate()`. However, the tags will not really reflect this, so they are not very useful. Should these all be merged to one tag? Or keep plyr and apply but merge the rest?

Note - I am willing to edit tags on questions but I don't have the rep to make new tags or synonyms or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. My preference in cases like this is to just include a language tag with the original tag, but many community members do not like that, for various reasons.  Tags can be searched simultaneously, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+apply.  I certainly don't think that the [r] community has the exclusive right to the [apply] tag, so if it is kept, the tag wiki will have to be changed.
2. I think [mapply], etc. should probably still be their own tags.  A function is a function is a function, and those tags are sufficiently specific to be unambiguous.  [aggregate] should probably be [r-aggregate], due to its ambiguity and the fact that it can refer to something other than a function.

Comment: So - what about uses of apply that are not a function in a language. Several of these questions seem to relate to applying a software patch of some sort, and in some cases apply seems to be just used in its plain language sense - how do I apply X function to Y data sort of thing - should [apply] be removed there?

Comment: Also, is it preferable to have one tag that needs to be modified by another (e.g [r][apply]and [javascript][apply) or is is better to have two tags that are clearer (e.g. [r-apply] and [js-apply])?

Comment: `Several of these questions seem to relate to applying a software patch of some sort` -- Just remove those tags.  As I said, I prefer that their be one callout of the method "apply" and modify it with a language tag.  Otherwise, you wind up with abominations like [c-if], [c++-if], [c#-if].  Ick.

Comment: I gave this a few days to see if there were any other opinions. Thanks for answering. I will look into the aggregate tag a little more carefully and start a thread on that in a few days.